# SQL query. Join right table as nested object inside left table

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

After reading through documentation I can't find anything about how to make this simple query:
there is two tables:

```
    first one is "PACKAGES"
       {
          id: 1,
          name: 'package_1',
          sender_id: 1,
          type: 'shipping'
       }
```

```
    second one is "USERS"
       {
          id: 1,
          name: 'user_1'
       }
```

When I perform Left, Right Join, or simply JOIN, its just merges this two tables into one. And id, name just overwrites with each other

What I need is:

```
       {
          id: 1,
          name: 'package_1',
          sender_id: 1
          type: 'shipping',
          user: {             // second table as nested object
              id: 1,
              name: 'user_1'
          }
       }
```

I tried everything that I can find, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM packages JOIN users AS user ON packages.sender_id=user.id;"
```

How I can put right table as an object inside left table?

Comment: `SELECT packages.*, users.* FROM packages JOIN users AS user ON packages.sender_id=user.id;`  ?

Comment: syntax error at or near "user"
...T packages.*, users.* FROM packages JOIN users AS user ON pa... it give s error

Comment: `SELECT packages.*, user.* FROM packages JOIN users AS user ON packages.sender_id=user.id;`

Comment: Can u tell me pls, will it give me the expected result? Right table will be inside left table as a nested object? not just merging two tables? I tried your two lines, still gives an syntax error.

Comment: Anyway thank u very much)

Comment: Actually I have no idea what you mean by `as a nested object`. SQL doesn't return objects. It returns rows. I think the question needs some clarity.

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: @AaronJ 
Stefanov gave perfect answer for my question.
Why u have no idea about "nested object"? 
Try the solution that Stefanov gave me, it works perfectly

Comment: I am not an expert at everything, only some things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `to_json` to *present* the query result as a nested JSON object:

```sql
select to_json(res) from 
(
  select p.*, to_json(u) "user"
  from packages p 
  inner join users u 
  on p.sender_id = u.id
) res;
```

Result:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "package_1",
  "sender_id": 1,
  "type": "shipping",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "user_1"
  }
}
```